# FFMPEG change bitrate only

Tags: android, ffmpeg, bitrate

I have .ts file with corrupted, lets call it, metadata. Bitrate value is 0, so mediaplayer cannot play that file. Rest of the file is fine (If I convert it, for example, into mp4 it can be played with no problem)but I dont want to convert it, I only need to modify bitrate value. I tried to modify it, but I had to copy that file, and it took much time. I dont want to modify fps,resolution,format,etc.., I only need to "rewrite" bitrate value. Is it possible ?

this is what I've tried so far (different variations):

```
"-i", inputFile, 
    "-b", "1500k", 
//  "-minrate", "1200k", 
//  "-maxrate", "2000k",
//  "-bufsize", "12000k",
//  "-ab", "64k", 
    "-vcodec", "libx264", 
//"-acodec", "aac", "-strict", "-2", 
//  "-ac", "2", 
//  "-ar", "44100", 
//  "-s", "1280x720", 
//  "-y",
   "-f", format,
outputFile
```

Comment: overload the MOOV setting for the bitrate when you config the player on the ..
dont use ffmpeg if you do not want to run a full transcode step. if you are only deal with audio track then look at API for "AudioTrack"

Comment: Thank you Robert, I've never heard of moov, so I started googling, and you were right, atom moov data was somehow wrong, but I fixed it with re-copying source file, it took less then second, so it is really fast. I Also tried to use another approach without using ffmpeg, but I wasnt successful. Your comment led me to solution for my problem, so thank you again.